# Website link shared on Facebook not displaying thumbnail and title

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website which is needed to be shared on Facebook. The problem is when I shared it on Facebook, the thumbnail and title are not displayed. Only the URL is displayed.

This is the website : https://artechno.usu.ac.id. You can see the source code there. The meta tag is now commented.

I have tested it on Facebook Debugger and it said "Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address." and "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present." (I already have a meta tag with og:type property").

Are there any solution? I have search many websites and even a website with no og meta tag can display a thumbnail. There are no effects whether I change the meta tag or not, the result of Facebook Debugger display the same.

Comment: Well I clicked on the link and it say server not found so I think there is a problem with your hosting service.

Comment: @Sand The website is hosted in my college server.

Comment: Is the server accessible from out side your campus network ? I think your server is not accessible from out side or in other words you server or network is not open to the WWW. Which means all you WAN side ports are closed if the port 25 and 443 (HTTPS) is closed then no one can access the site from our side your network which includes Facbook. If those ports are closed then you have to ask your campus net admins to open up the WAN side of the network,

Comment: The site is accessible but I don't know if it can be accessed from outside of Indonesia. The main domain `usu.ac.id` can display the thumbnail when shared on Facebook

Comment: If the site is accessible to WWW then it should be available to all you better check with you campus net admins.

Comment: Yes, http://www.artechno.usu.ac.id is not accessible. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes that is the issue that's why Facbook trackback gives that error you need to open up the WAN side of the network and make sure WWW requests can reach your URL other wise it wont work.